# Ошибка при запуске Telegram-бота на python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Я новичок в python, решил написать Telegram-бота с помощью библиотеки pytelegrambotAPI. Суть программы: пользователь вводит неправильный глагол, ему приходит сообщение с тремя формами этого глагола, переводом. При запуске кода в консоли вылетает большое кол-во ошибок [image: фото с ошибками]. Пробовал подключать бесплатные прокси, думал, что в этом проблема, но работает очень нестабильно (1 из 10 раз). А именно эта программа не запустилась ни разу. 
Вот код: [image: фото] (скрыл словарь с глаголами, в файле config.py только TOKEN бота).

Comment: Ваш бот не может подключиться к серверам телеграмма, потому что они блокируются на территории РФ. Выход или использовать прокси, но как вы уже заметили бесплатные быстро протухают. Как вариант можно бесплатно захостить бота на heroku.com, или pythonanywhere.com

Comment: Спасибо большое за совет, выложу на  heroku

Comment: Пробуйте поставить любой VPN и запускать скрипт. У меня тоже была такая проблема. Скачал VPN и все работает.